# How to append columns conditionally inside .select() in knex.js

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js, postgresql-9.5

What I am trying to achieve is to add column name inside `.select()` when conditions is met.
So my code is like below:

```
const type = req.query.type;

knex('some_table').select('id','name',knex.raw('case '+ type +'when 1 then some_table.type else null end'))
```

Problem with this code is that it returns null when `type != 1` but I want it to return nothing.

So basically, it should add 'type' column if `type = 1` if not then add nothing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So in this example, sometimes you want it to return 2 cols, sometimes you want it to return 3 cols?

Comment: yeah! that is exactly it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I suspect that you're not actually after a `CASE` statement. These are used to check column *values* and manipulate the result set. For example:

```
knex('some_table')
  .select(
    'id',
    'name',
    knex.raw(`CASE WHEN ${type} = 'Apricots' THEN 'Apricots!' ELSE 'Not an apricot!' END`)
)
```

or to use the simpler form,

```
`CASE ${type} WHEN 'Apricots' THEN 'Hey, it's an apricot.' END`
```

What you seem to be after, though it's not entirely clear, is conditionally selecting a column based on a querystring. This could be achieved prior to issuing the query:

```
const columns = [
  'id',
  'name'
]

if (req.query.type) {
  columns.push(req.query.type)
}

knex('some_table').select(columns)
```

I hope it should be clear that allowing users to specify which columns come back in a result set is open to abuse, so you should be very careful which kind of data can be specified.

If this wasn't what you intended, you might need to clarify your question a little.

Comment: Oh, man thanks a lot for your informative answers!
Helping me again)
I did not have enough critical thinking to get this memo. Thanks a lot!
I will check it soon whether it is right or not.

Comment: as always you are right! man I want to work with you) is it possible ?

Comment: Remember to validate `type` variable to protect the code from SQL injection. Could be even better to use parameter binding to pass the type in `knex.raw`, but I cannot say for sure if parameter bindings are supported in that position of SQL statement.

Comment: I was politely disagreeing, then realised you were `elhigu` from GitHub so presumably you would know! :D

Answer (score 0):

How about building up an array of column names dynamically however you want to add them (ex. array.push) then spreading them as arguments into the select call?

```
const myColumns = ['column1']

if (conditionIsTrue){
 myColumns.push('column2')
}

knex('some_table')
  .select(...myColumns) // <--- the ... here turns the array into individual args
```

Comment: It's also possible to do something like `const query = knex.select(a, b, c)` and then subsequently add more columns later e.g. `query.select(x, y, z)` before executing the query.